# React Native - import javascript file into another javascript file as text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I've got a `MyFirstPage.js` file which is something like this:

```
renderCards() {
  let icon = this.state.icon;
  ....
  ....
  ....
}
```

Which i write to render my cards inside my main render function! The point is, because it's getting too long (about 350 lines), i want to create another file and import this `renderCards()` **AS TEXT** so i can i have it in the `MyFirstPage.js` main render!
Please note that `let icon = this.state.icon;` which refer to the `MyFirstPage.js` state - so i have to import it **AS TEXT**.

I tried:

```
export default {
  renderCards() {
      ....
      ....
      ....
      }
}
```

but not working!

Any idea?

> Thanks in advance!

Comment: export default renderCards() {} should do the trick

Comment: @spakmad did you note that `let icon = this.state.icon;`?

Comment: Yeah read that too quickly. How about this:
```export default class RenderCards extends Component {
   render = () => {
      // pass whatever was originally state as a prop now.
   }```

Comment: @spakmad So you mean i can create another component and use props! No way to import a file as text then?

Comment: I see now why your question indicates you'd like to import the method as text. What is the rest of the renderCards method? Is it all JSX? Why not create a function that does what you need it to do with the icons, returning JSX, put that function in another file, import it in MyFirstPage.js and call it providing the icons as an argument from this.state

Comment: I know i have that way, just asking if i can import this new file as text!

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to import the file as text. Although I think it's pretty safe to say that if you're importing a js file as text, you'd doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can define code in a string and execute it in Javascript. We can use `eval()` to evaluate a String as a piece of code. This approach has a security, reliability, and performance concerns because `eval` can essentially inject code into your script, and that code is simply determined by what String is passed to it. That said, most Babel transpiling presets use strict mode, and this limits `eval` to some extent by ultimately not allowing it to instantiate new variables in the surrounding scope. What it can still do, is define a function and evaluate that function and assign it to a variable in the external scope like so:

```
var a = 5
var b = 10
var c = eval('function abc() { return a + b }; abc;')
assert(c() === 15)
```

With this ability in hand, we can wrap your entire 'renderCards' function definition in a String (by way of template literal):

```
export default `renderCards() {
  let icon = this.state.icon;
  ....
  ....
  ....
}; renderCards;`
```

Import this string (`import renderCardsImport from {relative path to file}` in the react component `MyFirstPage.js`, and in the constructor you need to do a few things:

```
constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.state = {
      icon: // whatever this is
   }
   let renderCards = eval(renderCardsImport)
   // so you have access to the parent class object this
   this.renderCards = renderCards.bind(this)
}
```

And now you should be able to call `renderCards()` in the `render()` method or anyplace else in the component. Phewww. That was a doozy, but learned so much about eval, strict mode, etc. Hope it helps.

EDIT: You can also use the `Function` constructor it appears, as in `var myFunct = Function('body of function with a return statement')` but you will need to remember to bind it to `this` as well. If you use Function, you avoid performance and security hit of eval. Strict mode takes away most of the reliability problems.

Comment: could you please give me an example?

Comment: I learned a bunch here. I updated answer with a working solution. Let me know if it works.

Comment: really thanks for your answer BUT i get SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' - and it's pointing to this line: `let renderCards = eval(renderCardsImport)`